# When i run my script all is fine, but when i import it in a Django project it has cascade import problems

Tags: python, django

I´m using [Dejavu (audio-fingerprints) - python3 branch](https://github.com/mauriciorepetto/dejavu/tree/dejavu_python_3.6.6) ... When i run a example script it is fine, but when i try to import in my django project shows this error:
[image]

---

I do both processes within the vEnv, however it only works in the first case.

The script is:

[image]

The import proccess is in a DjangoApp

[image]

I have verified that the problem is not in the import of the script but in the cascade of imports that are derived from it. This is my tree:

[image]

I insist that when I run the script in the terminal, it works.

Finally, I leave the tree of the dejavu library:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `pip install Dejavu` in your Django environment?

Comment: On the same environment it works when i execute it as an alone script (without the django)